# How do I properly calculate the load factor of a hash table that uses separate chaining?

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash-collision, load-factor

I'm working with hash tables that use separate chaining as a collision resolution technique.

I do know that the general formula is N/table_length, where N is the number of items currently in the table.

I'm a bit confused by the denominator. Would it be the size of the array + the number of chained elements, or simply the size of the array?

Comment: Isn't the proper load factor at least partially a matter of taste?  i.e. if you want to waste less memory, you'd specify a higher load-factor, but if you think it's more important to have faster lookup times, you'd specify a lower load-factor.

Comment: Yes, the load factor one chooses is a matter of taste, but I don't think that applies to how to properly calculate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of the [load factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics) is to give an idea of how likely (on average) it is that you will need collision resolution if a new element is added to the table. A collision happens when a new element is assigned a bucket that already has an element. The chance that a given bucket already has an element depends on how many elements are in the container.

`load factor = # of elements / # of buckets`

(In your terminology: the number of items currently in the table divided by the size of the array.)

Comment: Why would we not need to take the chained items into account? If we don't then the load factor can exceed 1, right?

Comment: @AdamG Yes, the load factor can exceed 1. Values over 1 indicate that the hash table can no longer operate at ideal performance. (Ideal performance occurs when there have been no collisions. Load factors over 1 indicate that collisions have definitely occurred.)